# Quantlib-python installed but not found

Tags: python, quantlib

newbie in Python I am trying to play around with quantlib-python on my basic Win10 64bits. So I installed the package from Pypi but it's not found in Python. here is the console:

pip install QuantLib-Python

Collecting QuantLib-Python
  Using cached QuantLib_Python-1.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 kB)
Collecting QuantLib
  Using cached QuantLib-1.18-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (9.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: QuantLib, QuantLib-Python
Successfully installed QuantLib-1.18 QuantLib-Python-1.18

Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import Quantlib as ql

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quantlib'

any idea how to solve this ? Am I supposed to compile the source code of Quantlib ?

Comment: Please properly format code, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
import QuantLib as ql
```

with a capital Q and a capital L.

Comment: Yes, that's it!